# How do I get to this island in the middle of nowhere in the north-east section of the map?

Tags: genshin-impact

I'm trying to get to this island in the middle of nowhere to the east of Stormbearer Point. There is an Anemoculus there that I need to grab and is the only one that I'm missing.

How do I get there? Gliding and Swimming is not an option because you don't have enough stamina.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get on this island by gliding. For this, you need to jump from the peak at Starsnatch cliff (on the red circle added to your picture).

[image: Starsnatch cliff peak]

In order to get enough stamina, you should increase your rank at the Anemo and Geo statues of the Seven to increase your max stamina. After that, you may use food that reduces stamina consumption during gliding like [Barbatos Ratatouille](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Barbatos_Ratatouille), and during the glide you may use food to regenerate your stamina, like [Northern Smoked Chicken](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Northern_Smoked_Chicken)

Comment: Worth including Amber in your team too, as she has a perk to reduce stamina cost when gliding

Comment: I was trying to go from Stormbearer Point and not Starsnatch Cliff, that is probably why I failed miserably as it was from lower altitude lol. Also, I don't have those two recipes so I should probably find them first.

Comment: I don't know this game, but how does one get back then?

Comment: Also, you can get to the islands by making ice bridges. With Kaeya, use your elemental skill to create a walkable ice path on top of the water, wait for the cooldown, then use it again to further the path. Do it until you reach the island.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: The "real" answer for this island is a bit spoilery, but you can just teleport away.

Comment: Similar to Kaeya, Ayaka also works to make an ice bridge over there, but it's a lot faster - you can use her alternate dash to speed across the water, then when you're low on stamina stop and use her E to freeze a section and wait for some stamina to come back, then start dashing again.